# How to select from a list of image options?

Tags: html, reactjs, select, input, tags

I'm trying to implement a design in which the select input displays a list of images to pick from.

```
<select name="choose-image">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your image</option>
    <option value="Smiling"><img src={image} alt="local-avatar" /></option>
    <option value="Sad">Sad</option>
</select>
```

The second option does not display anything and even if it did, I would need to style the dropdown list and I'm still unsure how to.
Appreciate any help. Thanks.